# WiX - Uninstalling old NSIS app before installing with WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

We are planning to ship a new version of a Windows app, and along with it replacing the older NSIS-based installer with a new MSI created with WiX. I am trying to perform a silent uninstall of the old app as part of the install flow:

```
<!-- Custom action to uninstall old app if it's already installed -->
<!-- 1.Check if old app is installed by checking if it exists in the registry -->
<Property Id="OLDAPPUNINSTALLERCOMMAND">
    <RegistrySearch Id="OldAppUninstallerRegistrySearch" Type="raw" Root="HKLM"
    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\12345"
    Name="QuietUninstallString" Win64="yes"/>
</Property>
<!-- 2. Create a custom action to uninstall old app -->
<SetProperty Id="RemoveOldApp" Value="[OLDAPPUNINSTALLERCOMMAND]"
            Sequence="execute" Before="RemoveOldApp" />
<CustomAction Id="RemoveOldApp" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="check" />
<!-- 3. Schedule the custom action after installer initialisation, if old app was found -->
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="RemoveOldApp" After="InstallInitialize">RemoveOldApp</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

If the old app was not installed then the action is skipped and the new app is installed as expected.

However if the old app was installed, the new WiX installer silently uninstalls it and then continues with the installation. Everything looks successful (the old app disappears from ARP and the new app appears), however the installation directory is empty. If I perform "Modify" on the new installation, the new files appear.

I suspect some sort of sequencing issue where the old NSIS installer is deleting the contents of the directory after the new WiX installer writes it's files to it or something, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

EDIT: I believe that the NSIS uninstaller is not blocking the WiX installer, I tested this by

- creating a pair of custom actions which print a msgbox before and after `RemoveOldApp` (and are also deferred), so that we can visibly see the start and stop of the NSIS uninstall flow
- modifying `RemoveOldApp` to run `UninstallString` rather than `QuietUninstallString`, so that we can visibly see the NSIS uninstaller.

New code:

```
        <CustomAction Id="BeginOldAppUninstall" Script="vbscript" Execute="deferred">
            <![CDATA[
                msgBox "Uninstalling OldApp"
            ]]>
        </CustomAction>

        <CustomAction Id="EndOldAppUninstall" Script="vbscript" Execute="deferred">
            <![CDATA[
                msgBox "OldApp uninstall complete"
            ]]>
        </CustomAction>

        <!-- Custom action to uninstall OldApp if it's already installed -->
        <!-- 1.Check if OldApp is installed by checking if it exists in the registry -->
        <Property Id="OLDAPPUNINSTALLERCOMMAND">
            <RegistrySearch Id="OldAppUninstallerRegistrySearch" Type="raw" Root="HKLM"
            Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\12345"
            Name="UninstallString" Win64="yes"/>
        </Property>
        <!-- 2. Create a custom action to uninstall OldApp -->
        <SetProperty Id="RemoveOldApp" Value="[OLDAPPUNINSTALLERCOMMAND]"
            Sequence="execute" Before="RemoveOldApp" />
        <CustomAction Id="RemoveOldApp" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="check" />
        <!-- 3. Schedule the custom action after installer initialisation, if OldApp was found -->
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="RemoveOldApp" After="InstallInitialize">RemoveOldApp AND NOT (REMOVE = "ALL")</Custom>
            <Custom Action="BeginOldAppUninstall" Before="RemoveOldApp">RemoveOldApp AND NOT (REMOVE = "ALL")</Custom>
            <Custom Action="EndOldAppUninstall" After="RemoveOldApp">RemoveOldApp AND NOT (REMOVE = "ALL")</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I expected to see:

- `BeginOldAppUninstall` message box
- click ok on `BeginOldAppUninstall`
- NSIS uninstall popup
- perform uninstall, NSIS unintsaller exits
- `EndOldAppUninstall` message box
- click ok on `EndOldAppUninstall`
- WiX installer finishes and exits

Instead I saw:

- NSIS uninstall popup and `EndOldAppUninstall` message box appear at the same time
- click ok on `EndOldAppUninstall`
- WiX installer finishes and exits
- NSIS installer is still there in background as it is not silent mode

So it looks like the NSIS uninstall isn't blocking the installer even though I have `Return="check"` set.

(Also, not sure why we aren't stopping on the `BeginOldAppUninstall` msgbox, but whatever)

EDIT 2: So turns out NSIS uninstallers copy themselves to a temp directory, execute the copy using the argument `_?=ABC` and then return, so that the original .exe can be deleted (more info [here](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/When_I_use_ExecWait_uninstaller.exe_it_doesn%27t_wait_for_the_uninstaller)). `_?=ABC` means to actually perform the uninstall on the original install location ABC. So now I have to figure out how to copy this uninstall .exe to a temp folder before executing. Progress!

Comment: Check the install log. What I suspect is happening is that MSI checks the file versions and then schedules only those files to be installed that aren't already there. Try giving [REINSTALLMODE=amus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/reinstallmode) to msiexec and see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: Only the application .exe matches the same name between the old and new versions, all other files (dlls, resource files e.t.c) are different. For the .exe I see the log `Disallowing installation of component: {xxx} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists` which I think is fine because the new exe looks like it's missing a version number. But all other files are also either mostly missing, or sometimes 1-2 of them exist after the install. What I was hoping though was to run the uninstall script early enough in the install flow to avoid these sorts of conflicts.

Comment: When using `REINSTALLMODE=amus` the new .exe does get installed, but most other files are still missing (or again sometimes 1-2 of them exist). The logs show nothing interesting for them I think - for each of them there is a log about `ComponentRegister` executing, a `FileCopy` operation log, a log that it is `To Be Installed` and `No existing file`

Comment: You're scheduling your custom action at the correct time and checking the return code too, thus presumably waiting for it to complete, so I'm not sure how the uninstaller would mess with the files being installed. But 1-2 files occasionally appearing does point at some sort of race. No idea what's going on if it's not spawning a background process to delete the files.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I did some more testing and think that the NSIS uninstall is not blocking the WiX install - updated my question, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: What you could do is to present a dialog to the user "old install detected, uninstalling. re-run the installation to complete it" and then exit early.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround for this type of scenario is to install the app to a new folder.